# Special characters in password causing internal server error "SQL Injection attack detected via libinjection"

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

I have an old custom php website that I've been working on. I have updated the php code and have a password reset functionality in place. I moved the Connections folder outside of the root folder as that is what I read was the recommended course of action. My client asked for the ability to use special characters in the password reset. I have regex for this that works great. Everything seems to be working, except when I try to use multiple characters in a row, I get an internal server error. When I check the error log this is what it says:

```
ModSecurity: Warning. detected SQLi using libinjection with fingerprint 'novc' [file "/dh/apache2/template/etc/mod_sec3_CRS/REQUEST-942-APPLICATION-ATTACK-SQLI.conf"][msg "SQL Injection Attack Detected via libinjection"] [data "Matched Data: novc found within ARGS:newPassword2: Abcd1234!@#$"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.2"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-sqli"] [tag "paranoia-level/1"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/152/248/66"]
```

This was not an issue on a test website I created, but I also have the database connection file in the root of the test website folder. In the live website I have the connection file outside of the project folder as I read this was best practice.

```
Connections folder
--connection.php
live website folder
--index.php
--other files, etc.

test website folder
--Connection.php
--other files
```

Here is my query to update the password:

```
// if form is submitted and the value equals the value of the hidden input
if (isset($_POST['newPassword'])) {
    // password regex match
  if (!preg_match('/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!#$%&()*@?^])[A-Za-z\d!#$%&()*@?^]{8,30}$/', $_POST['newPassword'])) {
    exit('password should be between 8 and 30 characters and contain at least one number and one special character');
  }
  // Check if both the password and confirm password fields match
  if ($_POST['newPassword'] != $_POST['newPassword2']) {
  exit('Passwords do not match!');
  }
  // set the date
  $month = date ("M");
  $year = date ("Y");
  $day = date ("j");
  // lastEditTime and lastEditedBy
  $lastEditTime = $month." ".$day.", ".$year; 
  $lastEditedBy = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
  $userId = $_SESSION['MM_UserID'];
  $newPassword = password_hash($_POST['newPassword'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
  $updateStmt = $connection->prepare("UPDATE tbl_users SET newPassword= ?, lastEditedBy= ?, lastEditTime= ? WHERE userID= ?");
  $updateStmt->bind_param('sssi',$newPassword,$lastEditedBy,$lastEditTime,$userId);
  $updateStmt->execute();
    $updateStmt->close();     

  header("Location: reset4.php");
  exit;
}
```

I have never encountered this problem before. Does anyone have any advice on how to correct this?

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question - are you e.g using parameterized queries?

Comment: [ModSecurity](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity) runs on top of your web server and has nothing to do with your PHP app. It's intercepting the request (before it even gets to PHP) because it looks like a SQL injection attack. If you want to allow it, you'll need to adjust the ModSecurity config, not your app.

Comment: Also note, you can do `$lastEditTime = date('M j Y');` in one line.

Comment: The code looks good otherwise, you're using strong hashing and bound parameters. Only suggestion I'd make security-wise would be to also prompt for the old password when prompting for the new password, and then verify it before running the update.

Comment: @AlexHowansky the website is hosted on Dreamhost and I am using SFTP to make changes. Do you know if I would I be able to access the ModSecurity config through SFTP? There is nothing on the Dreamhost Cpanel allowing me to make changes to ModSecurity.

Comment: No idea. If it's shared hosting you're probably out of luck. If it's a dedicated VPS, the config file is likely in /etc somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ModSecurity rules for SQL injection are blocking things that look like SQL injection - and that can lead to false positives.  These rules are likely coming from the [OWASP ModSecurity Core Rule Set](https://owasp.org/www-project-modsecurity-core-rule-set)

Generally you want to exclude a password field from ModSecurity Core Rule Set checking. This is normally done by adding to your ModSec config a rule like:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@streq /your/page/uri" \
"id:12345,phase:1,t:none,nolog,pass,\
ctl:ruleRemoveTargetByTag=.*;ARGS:password"
```

Sub in your own URL and your specific params.

I don't know how you would go about modifying your config in a Dreamhost environment (or even whether they allow that).  That is a seperate question.

Note also that ModSecurity should be configured to avoid logging the values from password and other sensitive fields. See "Removing Sensitive Data from Audit Logs" in the excellent [ModSecurity Handbook](https://www.feistyduck.com/library/modsecurity-handbook-2ed-free/online/ch04-logging.html).

Comment: Thanks @Egret I contacted Dreamhost support and they were able to fix the issue on their end.